# Integral involving sgn function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am having trouble with calculating or approximation the following integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(t^2-1)^{pn}(\mathrm{sgn}(t-1)-\mathrm{sgn}(t+1))^pdt,
$$
where $1\leq p<\infty$ and $n \in N$.

Any ideas or references would be very helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{\operatorname{sgn}} \sgn(t-1)- \sgn(t+1)=
\begin{cases} 
0, &\text{if } |t| \geq 1, \\
-2, &\text {if } |t| < 1 . 
\end{cases}
$$

$$\begin{align*}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(t^2-1)^{pn}(\sgn(t-1)- \sgn(t+1))^p \mathrm dt &=\int_{-1}^{1}(t^2-1)^{pn}(-2)^p \mathrm d t\end{align*}$$

**Hint:**

Essentially, the problem involves breaking up the integral into relevant pieces and looking the signum function in those pieces. For instance, when $t>1$, note that the integral vanishes and so on.